# Why might SetString intrinsic cause an "Incompatible types" error on PChar argument?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Please excuse the silly question, but I'm confused. Consider the following method (sorry for noisy comments, this is a real code under development):

```
function HLanguages.GetISO639LangName(Index: Integer): string;
const
  MaxIso639LangName = 9;  { see msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373848 }
var
  LCData: array[0..MaxIso639LangName-1] of Char;
  Length: Integer;
begin
  { TODO : GetLocaleStr sucks, write proper implementation }
  //Result := GetLocaleStr(LocaleID[Index], LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME, '??');
  Length := GetLocaleInfo(LocaleID[Index], LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME, @LCData, System.Length(LCData));
  Win32Check(Length <> 0);
  SetString(Result, @LCData, Length); // "E2008 Incompatible types" here, but why?
end;
```

If I remove the reference operator then implicit cast from `$X+` comes to the rescue and method compiles. Why compiler refuses this code *with reference operator* is beyond my understanding.

This is Delphi XE2 and this behaviour might be specific to it.

---

And if I add a test-case dummy with equivalent prototype as intrinsic one within the scope of `HLanguages.GetISO639LangName` this error will magically go away:

```
procedure SetString(var s: string; buffer: PChar; len: Integer);
begin
  { test case dummy }
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to explicitly convert it to `PChar`:

```
SetString(result,PChar(@LCData),Length);
```

As you stated, `SetString()` is very demanding about the 2nd parameter type. It must be either a `PChar` either a `PWideChar` either a `PAnsiChar`, depending on the string type itself.

I suspect this is due to the fact that `SetString()` is defined as overloaded with either a `string`, a `WideString`, or an `AnsiString` as 1st parameter. So in order to validate the right signature, it needs to have exact match of all parameters types:

```
SetString(var s: string; buf: PChar; len: integer); overload;
SetString(var s: AnsiString; buf: PAnsiChar; len: integer); overload;
SetString(var s: WideString; buf: PWideChar; len: integer); overload;
```

Of course, all those are "intrinsics", so you won't find such definition in system.pas, but directly some procedure like `_LStrFromPCharLen() _UStrFromPCharLen() _WStrFromPWCharLen()` or such.

This behavior is the same since early versions of Delphi, and is not a regression in XE2.

Comment: Ah, I got it! Due its intrinsic nature **and overload** for wider character type support!

Comment: I don't get the reasoning. If the actual parameters are compatible with only one of the overloads, then that should be fine. Note that `SetString` behaves differently from your own overloads.

Comment: This is because overloading is not handled by the compiler as usual, but internally to the compiler, mapping calls to _WStrFromPWCharLen() intrinsics or such. So expectations about 2nd parameters sounds to be more explicit than with a "normal" overload procedure.

Comment: OK, but that's all a bit of speculation. Clearly there's something a bit odd going on and we can't know what without have compiler source. Minor point. Your first sentence is too strong. You don't need to explicitly cast. You can just pass LCData as @oxo observed.

Comment: Arnaud is right, `_LStrFromPCharLen etc` functions has to be examined instead of intrinsic `SetString`

Comment: @user539484 My point is that if you declared the overloads yourself, then the behaviour would be different. Which looks like a compiler bug. Well, I'd class it as such. And what's more, the first sentence of the answer is demonstrably false. Pass `LCData` as oxo said, and there's no need to cast. It's a very interesting question. Compiler behaviour is odd.

Answer (score 4):

I think there's a compiler bug in there because the behaviour with `SetString` differs from the behaviour with overloaded functions that you provide. What's more there's an interaction with the Typed @ operator compiler option. I don't know how you set that. I always enable it but I suspect I'm in the minority there.

So I cannot explain the odd behaviour, and answer the precise question you ask. I suspect the only way to answer it is to look at the internals of the compiler, and very few of us can do that.

Anyway, in case it helps, I think the cleanest way to pass the parameter is like so:

```
SetString(Result, LCData, Length);
```

This compiles no matter what you set Typed @ operator to.

Comment: Very nice that all the comments from yesterday are gone and also who suggested to omit the @ operator...

Comment: @oxo My other answer got in a mess. Which is why I deleted it. I think there's room for an answer which goes into more detail. One that compares SetString overloads with your own overloads. And with and without typed @ operator. But I'm not in a position to write that answer. You could do so.

Comment: I was curious and checked the behaviour in Lazarus and FPC is fine with all sorts of parameters like: LCData, @LCData, PChar(@LCData), @LCData[0], PChar(@LCData), PChar(@LCData[0]). On the other hand Delphi likes only these three: LCData, PChar(@LCData), PChar(@LCData[0]). Interestingly, Delphi does not like @LCData[0] as it is - even if it is a valid PChar. So there must be some compiler magic behind it. + you definitely can pass zero-based array of char as PChar. + user1008646 has an interesting point too: nobody of us thought about omitting the SetString method :)

Comment: @oxo As I said, I'd call this a bug. Omitting SetString is cute. But I'm dubious about the massive behaviour shift between 0 and 1 based arrays.

Comment: Sorry for that, actually it was already user539484 who suggested to omit the reference operator, I just didn't read the post carefully.

Answer (score 3):

I know this doesn't answer the specific question regarding SetString, but I'd like to point out that you can do the same thing by simply writing

```
Result := LCData;
```

When assigning to a string, Delphi treats a static array of char with **ZERO** starting index, as a Null terminated string with maximum length. Consider the following:

```
var
  IndexOneArray  : array [ 1 .. 9 ] of char;
  IndexZeroArray : array [ 0 .. 8 ] of char;
  S : string;
  T : string;
begin
  IndexOneArray  := 'ABCD'#0'EFGH';
  IndexZeroArray := 'ABCD'#0'EFGH';
  S := IndexOneArray;
  T := IndexZeroArray;

  ShowMessage (      'S has ' + inttostr(length(S)) + ' chars. '
                + #13'T has ' + inttostr(length(T)) + ' chars. ' );
end;
```

This displays a message that S has 9 chars, while T has 4. 
It will also work when the zero-index array has 9 non-null characters. The result will be 9 characters regardless of what's in the following memory locations.

Answer (score 0):

Because `LCData` is pointer to the `array`, not to the `Char`. Sure, sometimes it happens that an array or a record or a class start with char-type variable, but consequences are not what statically-typed compiler should rely upon.

You have to take the pointer to a character in that array, not to the array itself.

```
SetString(Result, @LCData[Low(LCData)], Length);
```